# Matching objects with specified properties using Java

Tags: java, collections

I have 1,000,000 objects.
I need to match them with 4 different properties within a specified range .

1. Length (10meters - 20meters)
2. Breadth (12meters - 18meters)
3. Height (3meters - 6meters)
4. Color (RED)

A simple for loop does it but certainly isnt the most efficient way to go about it.
What type of collections should i be looking to implement? How should I've approached this problem.

Comment: How is "RED" a range of colors?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Do you have to do this once for the million objects, or is this something that needs to be done repeatedly with different property ranges? If only once, why is a simple loop not the most efficient way to go about it?

Comment: @ Ball....try n capcha the essence of the prob rather than finding one within in...=]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [NavigableSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html) might work for you. You would need to define a different [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for each of the properties. Basically, start with the set sorted by one property and get the subset that fits the range. Place the subset into another `NavigableSet` sorted by the `Comparator` for the second property... repeat.

But I don't think any of that beats O(n) time :P since the sort is O(nlogn). At the very least it is interesting.

Comment: I think this is what they were expecting for an answer. Coz at 1st glance the obvious choice is storing in a DB but I was told to think in terms of collections. Anyway thanks for the help..interview done n dusted...

Comment: One question though. How do I sort the set when its a range?

Comment: @Soothsayer_14, basically, the set is already sorted based on the Comparator used to construct it. So if you had Integer values between 1 and 10 and the query was for the range 3-6 you would use a combination of `subset(E,E)`, `floor(E)`, and `ceiling(E)` like so: `subset(floor(3),ceiling(6))`.

Answer (score 3):

A collection would have to load all the data into memory, which is horribly inefficient for a data set that big. You should be using a database - that's what they're designed for.

Comment: +1 - Agree. SQL to the rescue. Along those lines, there are in-memory and file-based databases that would allow SQL queries on them.